# Escape status within a string literal as argument of `String#tr`

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, ruby-1.9, tr

There is something mysterious to me about the escape status of a backslash within a single quoted string literal as argument of `String#tr`. Can you explain the contrast between the three examples below? I particularly do not understand the second one. To avoid complication, I am using `'d'` here, which does not change the meaning when escaped in double quotation (`"\d"` = `"d"`).

```
'\\'.tr('\\', 'x')      #=> "x"
'\\'.tr('\\d', 'x')     #=> "\\"
'\\'.tr('\\\d', 'x')    #=> "x"
```

Comment: Interesting. And why does `'\\rs'.tr('\\rs','x')` return `\\xx`?! I would have expected a return value of `xxx`. And in the [documentation example](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001199) `"hello".tr('aeiou', '*')`, `*` is shorter than `aeiou`, so what does *If to_str is shorter than from_str, it is padded with its last character*
mean? Is it a bug? Is it a fly? Is it Superman? :D

Comment: @Zabba It means that `"hello".tr('aeiou', '*#')` is the same as `"hello".tr('aeiou', '*####')`. :D

Comment: What output would you expect (don't execute it just yet, please!), from `'\\d'.tr('\\d','xx)` ? I don't expect what it *does* give..

Comment: @Zabba What I would have expected is 'xx'.

Comment: Zabba, obviously a syntax error. ;)

Comment: @nitro2k01, yes, that was a typo.. :) @sawa, yes I expected `xx` too, but the actual result is `\x` (at least on 1.8.7).

Comment: If I wanted to understand `tr`'s behaviour, as well as listing the three examples above, I would have seen how it handled normal characters when there's differences in string length.

Comment: Watch out does not work with UTF8 strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Escaping in `tr`

The first argument of `tr` works much like bracket character grouping in regular expressions. You can use `^` in the start of the expression to negate the matching (replace anything that doesn't match) and use e.g. `a-f` to match a range of characters. Since it has control characters, it also does escaping internally, so you can use `-` and `^` as literal characters.

```
print 'abcdef'.tr('b-e', 'x')  # axxxxf
print 'abcdef'.tr('b\-e', 'x') # axcdxf
```

## Escaping in Ruby single quote strings

Furthermore, when using single quotes, Ruby tries to include the backslash when possible, i.e. when it's not used to actually escape another backslash or a single quote.

```
# Single quotes
print '\\'    # \
print '\d'    # \d
print '\\d'   # \d
print '\\\d'  # \\d

# Double quotes
print "\\"    # \
print "\d"    # d
print "\\d"   # \d
print "\\\d"  # \d
```

## The examples revisited

With all that in mind, let's look at the examples again.

```
'\\'.tr('\\', 'x')      #=> "x"
```

The string defined as `'\\'` becomes the literal string `\` because the first backslash escapes the second. No surprises there.

```
'\\'.tr('\\d', 'x')     #=> "\\"
```

The string defined as `'\\d'` becomes the literal string `\d`. The `tr` engine, in turn uses the backslash in the literal string to escape the `d`. Result: `tr` replaces instances of `d` with x.

```
'\\'.tr('\\\d', 'x')    #=> "x"
```

The string defined as `'\\\d'` becomes the literal `\\d`. First `\\` becomes `\`. Then `\d` becomes `\d`, i.e. the backslash is preserved. (This particular behavior is different from double strings, where the backslash would be eaten alive, leaving only a lonesome `d`)

The literal string `\\d` then makes `tr` replace all characters that are either a backslash or a `d` with the replacement string.