# Replacing regex capture with the same capture and an extra string

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to escape certain characters in a string. In particular, I want to turn

`abc/def.ghi` into `abc\/def\.ghi`

I tried to use the following syntax:

```
1.9.3p125 :076 > "abc/def.ghi".gsub(/([\/.])/, '\\\1')
 => "abc\\1def\\1ghi"
```

Hmm. This behaves as if capture replacements didn't work. Yet, when I tried this:

```
1.9.3p125 :075 > "abc/def.ghi".gsub(/([\/.])/, '\1')
 => "abc/def.ghi"
```

... I got the replacement to work, but, of course, my prefixes weren't part of it.

What is the correct syntax to do something like this?

Comment: Cf. nitro2k01's answer to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926457/escape-status-within-a-string-literal-as-argument-of-stringtr).

Answer (score 1):

This should be easier

```
gsub(/(?=[.\/])/, "\\")
```

Comment: the slash inside the sq brackets should be escaped but otherwise it does the job. Thanks!

I'm still puzzled why my example didn't work though.

Comment: The only reason the slash has to be escaped is because `/` is used as the pattern delimiter, otherwise Ruby would parse it wrong and prematurely terminate the pattern, causing a syntax error. Using `gsub(%r{(?=[./])}, "\\")` should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to prepare a string to be used as a regex pattern, use the right tool:

```
Regexp.escape('abc/def.ghi')
=> "abc/def\\.ghi"
```

You can then use the resulting string to create a regex:

```
/#{ Regexp.escape('abc/def.ghi') }/
=> /abc\/def\.ghi/
```

or:

```
Regexp.new(Regexp.escape('abc/def.ghi'))
=> /abc\/def\.ghi/
```

From [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape):

> Escapes any characters that would have special meaning in a regular expression. Returns a new escaped string, or self if no characters are escaped. For any string, Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(str))=~str will be true.

```
Regexp.escape('\*?{}.')   #=> \\\*\?\{\}\.
```

Comment: I am not sure it works all the time. Try this: Regexp.escape("/")

Comment: Why is that wrong? `"/"` doesn't have to be escaped UNLESS you are using the same value as your pattern delimiter, and that doesn't apply if you interpolate the escaped string into a regex, as per my example, or use a different delimiter like `%r{/}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a block to `gsub`:

```
>> "abc/def.ghi".gsub(/([\/.])/) {|m| "\\#{m}"}
=> "abc\\/def\\.ghi"
```

Not nearly as elegant as @sawa's answer, but it was the only way I could find to get it to work if you need the replacing string to contain the captured group/backreference (rather than inserting the replacement before the look-ahead).